# Why is it so easy to deal with concurrency with Rx?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

A few months back, we introduce Rx into our codebase, and since then the codebase is getting more and more "reactive". I feel that it is really easy to introduce concurrency into the codebase with Rx, as not a single line of "locking" was used yet.

***However, I do not understand why it is easy with Rx when I can't explain it in words.***

Is it related to the ["Actor Model"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) and ["Functional Reactive Programming"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming) concept?

Can someone kindly enlighten me on this please?

Comment: If everything is immutable, there's no need to lock.

Comment: Also the monadistic approach to thread marshelling in my opinion reduces the amount of code required to do the typical Background worker pattern. `Observable.ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default).Select(DoStuff).ObserveOn(Scheduler.Dispatcher).Subscribe(UpdateUI)` in my opinion easily describes control flow AND threading flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main reason it's "easy" is because of the blood, sweat and tears poured into the Rx library by the very smart Dev team behind it at MS.

Look at the (open) source code to see just how much careful code goes into enforcing the Rx grammar and the parameterisation of when and where things run using Schedulers. That has plenty of defensive concurrent code in it. I suggest it's the grammar and Schedulers that bring the simplicity.

Using the model is quite easy, but achieving that simplicity was not trivial. You are benefiting from standing on the shoulders of giants that have hidden the complexity behind a neat and tidy API :)

Incidentally, there is still the odd trap for you to fall into... I'm sure you'll find one sooner or later! One example is that Subject<T>.OnNext() is not protected from concurrent access in Rx 2.x for performance reasons.

Comment: Then again. It is highly recommended to always think twice before using Subject<T> directly.

Comment: This is sometimes over stretched advice though, you often need to use it once (albeit often indirectly as part of an API to convert some non Rx source to IObservable). Bart de Smet covers this in one of his Channel 9 videos. I don't recall which one, but he indicated on a whiteboard how you can think of Subject as the start of the Rx sausage machine that gets you into the Monad.

Comment: Yep - just like List<T>.Add has to be synchronized, so does Subject<T>.OnNext